# How to write an Action when Approval Process Line item is created for the approval Process

Tags: approval-process

I have a requirement. When Processinstancelineitem created for process instance I need to update the current actor name in Target object record.

Please let me know what are the possible ways to implement it. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement, I think if you can do field update in approval process step it will be easy and best way to do.

Let suppose you have 2 steps -

So in initial submission action update currrent actor with the step 1 approver.

And as soon as step1 is approved or rejected,in approve or reject action update field with step 2 approver.

Hope I am making some sense. If there is different requirement please correct me.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I need to update one custom field in one custom object which is Target object in Process instance. when ever ProcessInstanceWorkItem created needs to update the custom field with Pending approver name.